# JavaScript for comparing combo date with date picker date

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, database

I want to select the date in combo box which is less-than or equal to date selected in date picker.
I am using this code. Note combo box contains the dates from database in an array.

But its not working as per my requirement.

```
function copytxt(){
        var w = document.getElementById("dateoil").value;
        document.getElementById("cb1").value <= w;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If "dateoil" represents date picker and "cb1" represents combo box.
Then from what I have understood, this might be helpful:

```
function copyText() {
        var dp = document.getElementById("dateoil").value;
        var cb = document.getElementById("cb1").value;
        if(cb <= dp) {
           cb = dp;
        }
   }
```

Assuming the combo box receives the data from database and its an array of positive decimal values. Then this could be one of the ways to achieve the desired output.

```
function setValue() {
        var dp = document.getElementById("dateoil");
        var cb = document.getElementById("cb1").value;
        var comboValues = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dp.length; i++){ 
            if(dp[i].value <= cb){
              comboValues.push(parseFloat(dp[i].value));
            }
        }
        dp.value = comboValues.sort().pop();
   }
```

Comment: cb=dp; will set the value of combo. combo may have same date or may be not. I want if cb-date is smaller then it should select nearest date lesser the date pickers date

Comment: @AshwaniKumarYadav I have edited the answer based on the said use case. It might be  what you are looking for.